# String manipulation with python and storing alphabets and digits in separate lists

Tags: python, string

For a given string s='ab12dc3e6' I want to add 'ab' and '12' in two different lists. that means for output i am trying to achieve as temp1=['ab','dc','e'] and for temp2=['12,'3','6'].
I am not able to do so with the following code. Can someone provide an efficient way to do it?

```
S = "ab12dc3e6"
temp=list(S)
x=''
temp1=[]
temp2=[]
for i in range(len(temp)):
    while i<len(temp) and (temp[i] and temp[i+1]).isdigit():
        x+=temp[i]
        i+=1
        temp1.append(x)
        if not temp[i].isdigit():
            break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also solve this without any imports:

```
S = "ab12dc3e6"

def get_adjacent_by_func(content, func):
    """Returns a list of elements from content that fullfull func(...)"""
    result = [[]]    
    for c in content:
        if func(c):
            # add to last inner list
            result[-1].append(c)
        elif result[-1]: # last inner list is filled
            # add new inner list
            result.append([])

    # return only non empty inner lists
    return [''.join(r) for r in result if r]

print(get_adjacent_by_func(S, str.isalpha))
print(get_adjacent_by_func(S, str.isdigit))
```

Output:

```
['ab', 'dc', 'e']
['12', '3', '6']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex, where you group letters and digits, then append them to lists

```
import re
S = "ab12dc3e6"

pattern = re.compile(r"([a-zA-Z]*)(\d*)")

temp1 = []
temp2 = []
for match in pattern.finditer(S):
    # extract words
    #dont append empty match
    if match.group(1):
        temp1.append(match.group(1))
        print(match.group(1))
    # extract numbers
    #dont append empty match
    if match.group(2):
        temp2.append(match.group(2))
        print(match.group(2))
print(temp1)
print(temp2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does nothing for isalpha - you also run into IndexError on

> ```
> while i<len(temp) and (temp[i] and temp[i+1]).isdigit():
> ```

for `i == len(temp)-1`.

---

You can use [itertools.takewhile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) and the correct string methods of [str.isdigit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) and [str.isalpha](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) to filter your string down:

```
S = "ab12dc3e6"

r = {"digit":[], "letter":[]}

from itertools import takewhile, cycle

# switch between the two test methods
c = cycle([str.isalpha, str.isdigit])

r = {}
i = 0
while S:
    what = next(c) # get next method to use
    k = ''.join(takewhile(what, S))
    S = S[len(k):]
    r.setdefault(what.__name__, []).append(k)

print(r)
```

Output:

```
{'isalpha': ['ab', 'dc', 'e'], 
 'isdigit': ['12', '3', '6']}
```

This essentially creates a dictionary where each seperate list is stored under the functions name:

To get the lists, use `r["isalpha"]` or `r["isdigit"]`.